# Can the path to V have spaces in it?

Tags: vlang

Can the path to V have spaces in it?

I tried to run `v fmt` and got this:

```
$ v fmt something.v 
sh: /Users/abcd/Library/Application: No such file or directory
Encountered a total of: 1 errors.
```

V resides in `~/Library/Application Support/vlang`
The path has a space in its name.

Perhaps related, the `v doc` command seems scanty; I expected a one-line summary of what each function does.

```
$ v doc os
...
fn base_dir(path string) string
fn cache_dir() string
fn chdir(path string)
fn chmod(path string, mode int)
...
```

Comment: Have you tried `v up` recently?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been fixed and in newer versions this behavior is not reproducible.

Comment: Sure, fine. It's only a year old. No need to give an answer now.